Jenkins: set default value of a parameter as the value of different one
I'm trying to support backwards compatibility, to do so I need to add set a hidden parameter and i want it to hold the value of other param, any ideas how to do this?
In the UI, at the default value part I would want to set: ${other_parameter_name}

Give us more context. Pipeline or freestyle? Why do you need the same value available under two different names?
